# Var value saving

Tags: java, variables, int

I Got a simple code with some int declared vars, The problem is, every time Another method in the code doing her thing, the variable "e" going back to its original one, At the code the value Is supposed to be decreasing by A random variable(Using x.nextInt();) the var is decreasing, but when going to another function in the class, the var is back to original.

Someone knows how to fix that?, thanks.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Showing your code would help. Are you sure you are setting the decrease? something like `e = e - x.nextInt()`?

Comment: Show the code. Anyway it looks like the usual "pass by value vs pass by reference" confussion.

Comment: We're not wizards. We can't spot bugs in code we don't even see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your variable is a parameter of the function, it's normal that it doesn't get changed inside the function. This happens because the function only receives a copy of the value of your variable, not a reference to the variable, so the original variable isn't changed.

This is called [passing by value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).